After creating an Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter - the default Ethernet adapter doesn't work
I am not sure if this is by design.
But I created an External Hyper-V Ethernet Adapter, and now I have 2 adapters: The original Ethernet adapter, and the vEthernet.
Edit: This is how I created the vEthernet switch: I created an External switch in Hyper-V Manager > Virtual Switch Manager > New virtual network switch. It then showed up alongside the original Ethernet adapter in Network Connections in the control panel
Both are enabled. But when I disable the vEthernet adapter, I do not have internet, even though the original Ethernet adapter is still enabled.
Is that normal? i.e. that it must be either the Hyper-V vEthernet adapter or the original one? Or I need to change their properties in order for both of them to work?

Sorry about that, I added an External switch via Hyper-V Manager>Virtual Switch Manager>New virtual network switch. It then showed up alongside the original Ethernet adapter in Network Connections in the control panel

@John What you listed are types of vswitches; "vEthernet" is the name of a vswitch. Different things.

It's normal if you create an "External" vSwitch. The original Ethernet interface is disconnected from the OS network stack so that it could be connected to the vSwitch instead, and the vSwitch is what remains connected to the OS. (For comparison, Linux "bridges" behave the same way.)
The vSwitch configuration needs to have "Allow management OS..." enabled, and then any manual IP address configuration you need to do has to be done on the vEthernet interface.

Got it, thanks. So it's either this or that. What would be the use of a vSwitch over the OS one? I currently am using the vSwitch, but I am not sure what are the uses. (I created it in an attempt to do something else which didn't work so I plan to remove it, but I'm curious what are the uses of it now)

It's part of Hyper-V, so its main purpose is to connect Hyper-V VMs. It's also possible to create multiple "vEthernet" interfaces on the host, each assigned to a different tagged 802.1Q VLAN.

If I was to create another vEthernet - who will be in "control" of the network? What I mean is, when I created a single vEthernet - it took control from the OS adapter and it is now the one providing internet access. But if I created a second one - who would take over?

There's nothing to "take over"; Ethernet switches work at a local level and don't care about internet access. If you created two vEthernet interfaces (on the same vSwitch or otherwise), it would be exactly like having two real Ethernet ports connected via cables to a physical switch, and both would be active on the local level – the OS would still be the one selecting the gateway it wants to use for IP.

Thanks! My confusion is because of this though: https://imgur.com/a/oF46YgB. After I created the vEthernet Hyper-V Switch, it was the one that made the PC itself have internet, because when I disabled it - I did not have internet access, even though the OS one was still enabled. So I was sure that now the vSwitch is the one in charge for the internet access? Otherwise why I do not have internet access when I disable it and the OS one is still enabled? Only when I completely remove it, the OS adapter returns to work (the Realtek one)

The switch is in charge of your Ethernet access (it's in between the OS and the physical Ethernet port now), and your Internet access goes on top of that, but that doesn't mean the switch directly deals with Internet access as such – there is a relationship but it's rather more indirect.

So if I were to create another switch - it must be only 1 that is in charge of the Ethernet access? If theoretically I created another vSwitch, and both were enabled - who would be in charge of the Ethernet access? From my understanding, there can only be one in charge?

Right, I don't think Hyper-V would actually allow you to create two separate external switches that are both attached to the same physical Ethernet port. You can try, but it wouldn't make any practical sense for it to allow that. (Meanwhile, multiple vEthernet interfaces on the same vSwitch are the opposite situation and are possible.)
